# Need help editing files in place with sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed, terminal

I am trying to add a file in place with sed and I keep getting this error message

```
sed: 1: "test.txt": undefined label 'est.txt'
```

This is the command I am using

```
Desktop > sed -i 's/White/Black/' test.txt
```

I am not sure what I am doing incorrect here.... Any help will be really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some versions of `sed` require an argument for `-i`.  Try:

```
sed -i.bak  's/White/Black/' test.txt
```

Or (OSX/BSD only),

```
sed -i ''  's/White/Black/' test.txt
```

As you know, `-i` tells `sed` to edit in place.  The argument the extension to use for the back-up of the original file.  The argument is the empty string, your `sed` will likely not keep a back-up file.

GNU `sed` does not require an argument for `-i`.  BSD `sed` ([Mac OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html)) does.

#### Details

Consider the command:

```
sed -i 's/White/Black/' test.txt
```

If your `sed` requires an argument to `-i`, then it would believe that `s/White/Black/` was that argument.  Consequently, it believes that the next argument, `test.txt`, is the `sed` command that it should execute.  This would be interpreted as the "test" command `t` with the intention of jumping to the label `est.txt` if the test is true.  No such label has been defined.  Hence the error message:

```
sed: 1: "test.txt": undefined label 'est.txt'
```

#### Alternative

ThatOtherGuy reports that the following will run without error on all platforms:

```
sed -i -e 's/White/Black/' test.txt
```

ThatOtherGuy notes that the behavior of this line is, however, platform-*dependent*.  With BSD `sed`, it creates a back-up file with a `-e` extension.  With GNU `sed`, no back-up is created.

Comment: Aha! That makes a lot sense. Thank you so much for the explanation dude. And btw both commands you specified worked well!

Comment: `sed -i -e '...'` can be used on both GNU and OSX.

Comment: @thatotherguy So, on OSX, it is not possible to use `-e` for a back-up extension?  Very good.  I updated the answer to include your code.

Comment: @John1024 It is! The thing is that on OS X it uses `-e` as a backup suffix while on GNU it sees `-e` as introducing the sed command, and either way it's valid and modifies the file.